# Specializing "type argument" with "non-type argument" (or the other way around)

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

What I'd like to achieve is demonstrated with the toy-example below.

```
#include <cstddef>

template<size_t ElementSize>
class Buffer
{
public:

    char buffer[ElementSize];
};

template<typename T>
class Buffer<sizeof(T)>
{
public:

    char buffer[sizeof(T)];
};

int main()
{
    Buffer<4> b1;   // buffer with 4 bytes
    Buffer<int> b2; // buffer with space for "int"
}
```

This code obviously doesn't compile:

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp:12:7: error: template argument ‘sizeof (T)’ involves template parameter(s)
 class Buffer<sizeof(T)>
       ^
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:22:12: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<long unsigned int ElementSize> class Buffer’
  Buffer<int> b2; // buffer with space for "int"
            ^
test.cpp:22:12: error:   expected a constant of type ‘long unsigned int’, got ‘int’
test.cpp:22:16: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
  Buffer<int> b2; // buffer with space for "int"
```

Is there any way I could have two specializations of such template - one using explicit size in bytes (non-type argument), the other taking the size (with `sizeof()`) from the type `T` (type argument)? I'm interested in a solution that doesn't need two separate templates with distinct names or any `#define` macros.

I tried to implement that in "reverse" - having the `<typename T>` as the primary template and the one using `size_t` as the specialization (passing `char[sizeof(T)]` or `std::aligned_storage<...>::type` to the primary template), but that fails too.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. Once we have `template <size_t Size> class Buffer`, we're pretty limited to what we can do as far as specializations go. Namely, §14.5.5/8.1:

> A partially specialized non-type argument expression shall not involve a template parameter of the
>   partial specialization except when the argument expression is a simple *identifier*. *[Example:*
>
> ```
> template <int I, int J> struct A {};
> template <int I> struct A<I+5, I*2> {}; // error
>
> template <int I, int J> struct B {};
> template <int I> struct B<I, I> {}; // OK
> ```
>
> *- end example ]*

So the only partially specialization we could do is:

```
template <size_t I> class Buffer<I> { .. };
```

which runs afoul of §14.5.5/8.3

> The argument list of the specialization shall not be identical to the implicit argument list of the primary template.

In the other direction, we run afoul of 14.5.5/8.4:

> The specialization shall be more specialized than the primary template

And in no way is a `size_t` more specialized than a `T`.

What you could do instead is just create an alias:

```
template <size_t ElementSize>
class Buffer {
    char buffer[ElementSize];
};

template <typename T>
using BufferFromType = Buffer<sizeof(T)>;    

// or, if not C++11, another type
template <typename T>
class BufferFromType : public Buffer<sizeof(T)> { };
```

Comment: I'm not thrilled with this answer. There's got to be a better way to explain this from the standard, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Class templates cannot be overloaded. If a class template `Buffer` takes a non-type parameter of type `size_t`, then each time you write `Buffer<thing>` the `thing` has to be a valid non-type argument; it can't be a type. The reverse is also true - if `Buffer` takes a type parameter, then each time you write `Buffer<thing>` `thing`'s got to be a type.

The template arguments of partial specializations are always *deduced* during partial specialization matching; you can never explicitly specify them.

Function templates, however, can be overloaded. So you can write overloading `make_buffer`s and use `auto`:

```
template<class T> Buffer<sizeof(T)> make_buffer() { return {}; }
template<size_t Size> Buffer<Size> make_buffer() { return {}; }

auto buffer1 = make_buffer<int>();
auto buffer2 = make_buffer<42>();
```

And you can use `decltype` to achieve a uniform, but tortured syntax:

```
decltype(make_buffer<int>()) buffer1;
decltype(make_buffer<42>()) buffer2;
```

You can then write a macro for this easily.